# ShowDialog and Dispose problem with Forms..NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Im fixing some errors in an existing C# project.
I use Visual Studio 2008 and 3.5 .NET Framework.

The application uses Forms, and the lifecycle of the application worked correctly. I didn't did any changes yet, but the client started experiencing strange behaviour lately.
The can use the app the first time without problems, but if a form is closed and we open another one, the objects in this form are Disposed.
The code is for a PDA, and we have a EventHandler for the Scan.
I belive this is very strange as nothing from the code has been changed.
Maybe it is some framework bug?

I've tried to completely eliminate the event handlers on the Closing event, but the same error happens.
Changing the way the forms are disposed.

Form creation

```
 FormTEntreUbicaciones form = new FormTEntreUbicaciones(Movements.TREntreUbicaciones);            
                        form.ShowDialog();
                        form.Dispose();
```

Event creation

```
   if (Device.GetOSType2() == Device.OSType.WinMobile){
                    hDcd = new DecodeHandle(DecodeDeviceCap.Exists | DecodeDeviceCap.Barcode);
                    DecodeRequest reqType = (DecodeRequest)1 | DecodeRequest.PostRecurring;
                    dcdEvent = new DecodeEvent(hDcd, reqType, this);
                    dcdEvent.Scanned += new DecodeScanned(dcdEvent_Scanned);
                }
```

The form should be open, and all the objects in it should NOT be disposed

Exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
  Message="ObjectDisposedException"
  ObjectName=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeHelper(Delegate method, Boolean fSynchronous, Object[] rgobjArgs)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
       at Datalogic.API.DecodeEvent.WaitForScan()
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi please do not chane exception to `qoute` ... it is less readable then `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

After figuring out what was going wrong, I found out that the SCAN event was kept alive.

I added a Closing override:

```
 this.Closing += MyClosedHandler;
```

And the MyClosedHandlerEvent as follows:

```
        //FIX MA 23.07.2019
        protected void MyClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dcdEvent.IsListening)
            {
                dcdEvent.StopScanListener();
            }

            if (hDcd != null)
            {
                hDcd.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Problem was detected with datalogic.api.dll. The PDA used is the Skorpio x3.

Hope this will help somebody else!